# Want to use Google Analytics instead of firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-analytics

Hello I have a react native android mobile app. When I try to create a project in Google Analytics site, it always ask me to connect to Firebase - which I don't want to use. Although I want to track screens and events in a mobile app, I want to use GA because it has the feature I want like manual tracking of screens and custom dimension.

So how do I do this?

Comment: according to [this,](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track Android apps. **If you choose to use Google Analytics Services SDK for Android, continue with this guide.**

Comment: The mobile SDKs are being sunsetted starting Oct 2019. There is an article about it on one of the GA Cert. Partner sites that is an interesting read  
https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/google-to-sunset-support-for-google-analytics-services-sdk-transitions-mobile-analytics-to-firebase

Answer (score -1):

Google analytics is part of firebase. As far as I know the only way to use Google analytics is through firebase

Comment: Nope. [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start) and [Google Analytics Mobile App Implementation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/mobile-implementation-guide) are different.

Comment: The top of that second page says "Important: New users should use the Firebase SDK to track Android apps."